# Etymology of "Wincolmlee"

Tags: etymology, toponyms

In my travels around northern England I have found myself in *[Wincolmlee](http://www.davidjessop.co.uk/oldriverhull.html)* in the fair city of Kingston-upon-Hull, and also near *[Wincomblee](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=wincomblee&client=ubuntu&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=607&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3lYiT5cTKAhULwBQKHarCAgUQsAQIKg)* in Newcastle-upon-Tyne. These places are both on the riverside in less salubrious parts of their respective cities. I wonder if there is a common origin for the names. This source [here](https://thisisyogic.wordpress.com/tag/wincolmlee/) has the (Hull) Wincolmlee as meaning:-

> a field in the corner of an island

Is this the correct origin of the word? Are there any other places similarly named?

Comment: That source makes a bald statement, without explanation or references: I don't know what elements it is referring to. I haven't found another etymology (apart from a very fanciful one about a tavern keeper), for either of the names. They could be related (and the 'b' in Wincomblee intrusive, like pronouncing "chimney" as "chimbley". On the other hand, "combe" is an established place-name element (meaning 'valley') so they could be different. It is always risky to compare the current form of place names, as they have often changed so much in their history.

Comment: @ColinFine, it is true that the _Wincomblee_ is in a valley and _Wincolmlee_ isn't. The places are otherwise similar - riverside, wharf, industrial.

Comment: So? We cannot guess what properties were relevant to their being named, whenever that happened. If they are old, then "industrial" is probably not relevant, and "wharves" may or may not be.

Comment: @BrianHooper, a wave of nostalgia swept over me as I read your post.  In fact, you could call it Ostalgie, since I grew up near Hull and remember Wincolmlee well, but now live in/on Merseyside.

Comment: @BrianHooper, just a thought.  Since Wincolmlee seems to have been a place, and is now a street that follows *bends* in the River Hull, I thought of OE 'wincel' [approx. pronounced 'winkle'] = bend.  'Lee' can mean wooded place or clearing in a wood, but I can't suggest anything for that 'm'.

Comment: @Fard Nice to be involved in a bit of local (to me) history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see if we can elaborate on [David's comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/302120/etymology-of-wincolmlee#comment681521_302120) on your post:

[**Wincel**](http://www.bosworthtoller.com/035846) was an Anglo-Saxon word meaning *corner*, and was used in place names:

> **wincel:** (?) *a corner;* cf. place-names, e.g. Wincel-cumb, [...]
>    *Aldwinkle* (Northants).
>   [...] The word is found in place-names [...]

And perhaps **lee** is the same as [**lea**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lea) (meaning *grassland*), which comes from the Old English [**leáh**](http://www.bosworthtoller.com/021257):

> **leáh:** *A lea, meadow, open space, untilled land*.

So a wild guess would be that *Wincolmlee* and  *Wincomblee* (now two street names) are both originally from *wincel-lea*: *grassland at a corner*. If this is the case, then they are aptly named so, because these two roads are on the banks of two rivers (River Hull and River Tyne, respectively), and each of them are located at a sharp bend that forms a *corner*:

[***Wincolmlee***](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Wincolmlee,+Hull,+Kingston+upon+Hull,+UK/@53.7522444,-0.3353267,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x4878be3e6b2d4b75:0x9e26d2bead7886b8): [image]

[***Wincomblee***](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Wincomblee+Rd,+Newcastle+upon+Tyne,+Tyne+and+Wear+NE6+3PF,+UK/@54.9687276,-1.5411956,17z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x487e706b42d80135:0x64638168cf7c12a): [image]

Considering these facts, it seems highly unlikely that these place names should have nothing to do with the word *wincel*.

Some other place names with (a trace of) *wincel* in them: [*Wincham*, *Winchcombe*](https://books.google.com/books?id=MloRAQAAIAAJ&dq=wincel%20corner%20name&pg=PA105#v=onepage&q=wincel%20corner%20name&f=false), [*Wigglesworth*](https://books.google.com/books?id=hffkAAAAMAAJ&q=wincel+wigglesworth&dq=wincel+wigglesworth&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwifs_e6uvTKAhUMDiwKHSxtDeAQ6AEIHDAA), etc.

---

Now, there are other possible theories about *Winkolmlee* too:

- [One](https://thisisyogic.wordpress.com/tag/wincolmlee/) states that Wincolmlee *literally means ‘a field in the corner of an island’*.
  *Field* (-lee) and *corner* (Wincol-) are reasonable enough, but I personally don't know where *of an island* came from. From the -m- that's in between?
- [Another one](https://books.google.com/books?id=ujkBAAAAQAAJ&pg=PR8&dq=Wincolmlee+origin&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiXypetofTKAhVV-mMKHcbGCXkQ6AEIMDAE#v=onepage&q=Wincolmlee%20origin&f=false) tells this story to show that *Winkolmlee* is derived from the name of an owner, ***Lincolne Leigh***:

  > The great obscurity which attaches itself to the names of some of the streets of this town, is also fully cleared up by these MSS, such are the "Land of Green Ginger," "Wincolmlee," "Fulke Street" and "Sewer Lane," [...] The next explanation refers to "Wincolmlee," at [**page 259**](https://books.google.com/books?id=ujkBAAAAQAAJ&dq=259%20lyncolne%20leigh&pg=PA259#v=onepage&q=259%20lyncolne%20leigh&f=false), it will be seen that a considerable portion of the land in this locality originally belonged to Mr. Alderman Trippett, who sold it to a miller named "**Lincolne Leigh**," who had his mill in the neighbourhood.
- [Another one](https://books.google.com/books?id=oSVTAAAAYAAJ&dq=wincolmlee%20origin&pg=PA326#v=onepage&q=wincolmlee%20origin&f=false) tells yet another story:

  > Wincolmlee is a continuation of Trippet. The origin of this name is unknown. We should suppose that it was once the **ley** or ground of a family named **Wincolm**. According to Hadley it derives its name from the following curious circumstance: One Mrs. Reed, who once kept an alehouse in that neighbourhood, was wont, when in her cups, to amuse her customers with incredible stories, winking at the same time to her intimates, who knew her faculty of dealing in the marvellous; hence she obtained the title of *Wink-and-lie* or *lee*. Her house become so noted that it was usual for persons to make parties to spend the evening at Wink_and_Lee's to hear a good story; and in process of time it gave the name to all that part of the parish, which continued after her death, and which it still retains. The north end of Wincolmlee, between the two ferries that eross the Hull, was formerly called Wapping.

As to *Wincomblee*, I couldn't find any stories.